# Spring data Jpa with one-to-many relationship, entity as a parameter in constructor

Tags: spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, thymeleaf

I am developing a spring crud thymeleaf application representing work with two entities (Subject and TeacherTask).
These entities have one-to-many relationship.
TeacherTask is a file which the user can upload to the browser and then download

This is my TeacherTask entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class TeacherTask {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_task")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fileName")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "fileType")
    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data", length = 100000000)
    private byte[] data;

    @Column(name = "deadL")
    private Date deadL;

    @Column(name = "downloadURL")
    private String downloadURL;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subj_id")
    private Subject subject;

    public TeacherTask() {

    }

    public TeacherTask(String fileName, String fileType, byte[] data, Date deadL, String downloadURL, Subject subject) {

        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.data = data;
        this.deadL = deadL;
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
        this.subject = subject;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    public Date getDeadL() {
        return deadL;
    }

    public void setDeadL(Date deadL) {
        this.deadL = deadL;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getDownloadURL() {
        return downloadURL;
    }

    public void setDownloadURL(String downloadURL) {
        this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

In my TeacherTask controller comes a method for uploading files:

```java
@PostMapping("/uploadFile/{id}")
public String uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(value = "deadL") Date deadL,
        Model model, 
        @PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
         
    Subject subject = subjectService.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    System.out.println(fileName);

    String downloadURL = "http://localhost:8080/downloadFile/" + fileName;

    TeacherTask teacherTask = new TeacherTask(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes(), deadL, downloadURL, subject);

    teacherTaskService.save(teacherTask);
        
    model.addAttribute("files", teacherTaskService.findAll());
    
    return "subjectPage";
}
```

My problem is that if I don't identify Subject as a parameter in TeacherTask constructor, I will get a foreign key of Subject in TeacherTask table in database as null.
Is there a way to get a non-null value of this foreign key in DB without identifying Subject in TeacherTask constructor?

Is it a right way to put an object of entity to another entities constructor? Any alternatives?

```java
public TeacherTask(String fileName, String fileType, byte[] data, Date deadL, String downloadURL, Subject subject) {

    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.fileType = fileType;
    this.data = data;
    this.deadL = deadL;
    this.downloadURL = downloadURL;
    this.subject = subject;

}
```

This is how my TeacherTask table looks if I don't put Subject in TeacherTask constructor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly implemented you need to link those 2 entities. When you create a new child entity you need to link it to its parent before you save it so that the foreign key is correctly set in the database to link it to the parent entity.

Another option would be to use the `subject` setter in the child:

```java
// uploadFile(...)

TeacherTask teacherTask = new TeacherTask(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes(), deadL, downloadURL);
// link the child to parent
teacherTask.setSubject(subject);

teacherTaskService.save(teacherTask);
```

this way you can have a constructor without the `Subject` but it's ok either way.